# mongodb filter all longitude and latitude within radius

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongodb database with longitude and latitude.
What I want is return all data with longitude and latitude within 1KM  radius or higher.

```
{
   user:rex,
   longitude: 24,
   latitude: 20

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To filter collection in **MongoDB** with radius at first create the geospatial index.

If your collection name is `user` then

```
db.user.ensureIndex({loc:"2d"})
```

You need to convert the radius value to km. By default mongodb `$near` accepts `$maxDistance` as radius.

Now you can search within `1km` radius

```
 db.user.find({ loc : { $near : [yourLat,yourLon] , $maxDistance : 100/111.12 } } )
```

for more [MongoDb version 2.2 doc](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2/applications/geospatial-indexes/)